# mysql_affected_rows() always return 0

Tags: php, mysql

I need to update mysql table, and get the number of tables updated using php, the code look like below,

```
    $query = "update ACCESSUSERS set ACTIVE='111' where UPPER(USERNAME)=UPPER('firstname') and PINNUMBER='7777'";
    mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    $numrows = mysql_affected_rows();
    printf("Records updated: %d\n", $numrows);
```

But the issue is the above print 0 always even if changed the value for `ACTIVE` with different one.

What can be the issue, any help will be appreciated.

Note: I have tested the above query from phpMyadmin and it's working, only problem while executing in a php.

Thanks,
Haris

Comment: RTM http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php - `int mysql_affected_rows ([ resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )` and you're mixing APIs; *no wonder*. Here http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `mysqli_` API to make your database query.

You are using the obsolete `mysql_` API to count the rows.

You can't switch APIs and expect them to interact with each other. Stick to `mysqli_`.

Use [`mysqli_affected_rows`](http://php.net/mysqli_affected_rows) instead of `mysql_affected_rows`

Comment: Thanks it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the mysqli version of affected_rows. Which is

```
$numrows = mysqli_affected_rows($conn);
```

Comment: `num rows`? wrong function. edit: well... maybe. OP's using wrong terminology. but am pretty sure they want to use affected_rows here. It's an UPDATE and not a SELECT.

Comment: Ah yeah. Thanks for spotting

Comment: To add to @Fred-ii- the OP is also Clearly not using OOP so `mysqli_affected_rows($conn)`

Comment: thing is though, they might be using a procedural method to connect with, while you're using an object oriented method. Just in case, mixing both methods isn't always good.